# How to access Ubuntu 12.04 from a multi-boot system?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, dual-boot

I had Windows 7 installed on my machine, and then late I've  installed Windows 8 (dual boot), and they work fine together.

Windows 8 was normally loaded, but to load windows 7 I had to reboot the machine first from Win8 boot menu.

Now, after installing Ubuntu 12.04, I can access Windows 7 normally, but when I want to access Windows 8 I can't, system reboot and I am again on GRUB loader.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) URL.

Comment: try to run Linux an use command `sudo update-grub`. And tell us if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repair Windows booting first.

This will write Windows MBR !

Can be done using StartUp Repair from Windows 8 DVD/USB
or use ["Dual-boot Repair" utility](http://www.boyans.net).

Then you can either triple-boot over Windows boot manager
or over GRUB - it is your choice:

- [Dual-boot Windows and Linux](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html) (Windows boot
  manager in control)
- [Reinstall GRUB to MBR - Using Live CD - section 13](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275)